# On restoration of already purchased product a popup appears with message "the Apple Id is invalid for purchases in US iTunes Store"?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented InAppPurchase for non-consumable product in my project.I am providing a "Restore" button in app to restore the already purchased product if user delete app and reinstall it. But here is the one test case -

**1)** User install app and purchase product with a sandbox tester account

**2)** Logout the iTunes account from setting

**3)** User delete app and reinstall it

**4)** Click on restore button, a popup appears for signin with already existing account, user click on it and enter another(new) sandbox tester account.

**5)** a popup appears giving message "the Apple Id is invalid for purchases in US iTunes Store"

Why this message appears? When user click on Buy button and uses the same new tester account, the purchase is successful but not giving message something like you have not purchased the product because user is using new account while restoring!!

UPDATE 1 -
How is this possible???!!! Now i purchase product with one id and delete the app and again reinstall app.Now i click on restore button and sign in with new tester id and product restores!!!!! How is it possible if i did not purchase with the new id, then why it is restoring the product??

Answer (score 0):

I too got this popup `the Apple Id is invalid for purchases in US iTunes Store` Initially when I create a new sandbox tester account and used,But Once Uninstalled the build again ran I got a `Sign In` popup. `Restore` Option If there is no Product Purchased then its transaction queue is empty.

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
  {
  if( queue.transactions.count == 0 ) {

  }else {
    // Get product Id Already Restored
   }
 }
```

Comment: Did you again sign in with the same new id?? and what was the message this time?

Comment: Ya again used a same id after uninstall,At that time will get a `Sign In` popup.

Comment: But how is this possible???!!! Now i purchase product with one id and delete the app and again reinstall app.Now i click on restore button and sign in with new tester id and product restores!!!!!  How is it possible if i did not purchase with the new id, then why it is restoring the product??